# Suddenly, no sound

Tags: sound

I'm running Kubuntu 18.04. This morning I woke up to discover that sound
wasn't working at all.  Even doing **aplay** on a simple .wav file produced no sound. The **aplay** test is the lowest-level one I know.  **alsamixer** shows only SP/DIF.  I've ruled out hardware problems, since the sound is there when I switch to a different user.

My guess is that the sound is somehow being muted.  There should be a loudspeaker icon among the group of small icons at the right end of the taskbar, and it's not there.

How can I get my sound back?

Answer (score 0):

The answer, which I have just added to [No loudspeaker icon on taskbar, Kubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1272747/no-loudspeaker-icon-on-taskbar-kubuntu-18-04/1273963#1273963), is to install the **kubuntu-desktop** module.  And just to be sure, install the **indicator-sound** module in case it isn't there.