# No loudspeaker icon on taskbar, Kubuntu 18.04

Tags: sound

I'm running Kubuntu 18.04. In Xenia 20.04, it seems that you need the modules indicator-sound and indicator-sound-gtk2 to get the volume control on the taskbar.  But that doesn't work in 18.04.  So what do I need?

I think the problem lies in some configuration file, since when I created  new user, that user did have the sound indicator.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
sudo apt-get install indicator-sound
killall unity-panel-service
killall gnome-panel
```

or

```
sudo apt-get install indicator-sound
sudo apt-get install indicator-messages
sudo apt-get install evolution-indicator
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't help.  Those programs were already there.  I tried reinstalling them anyway -- no difference.  I suspect the problem lies in some configuration flle.

Comment: I discovered a very relevant thread here:https://askubuntu.com/questions/976375/kubuntu-17-10-no-audio-devices-found-no-settings-no-sound but no clear solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can even try this, it worked for me.<sup>*</sup>

```
sudo apt-get purge pulseaudio
sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Reboot. Open a terminal again and type (ignore any errors with the `rm` command):

```
rm -r ~/.pulse ~/.asound* ~/.pulse-cookie ~/.config/pulse
sudo apt-get install pulseaudio
```

Note: if you get `E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.` error, then you can try:
`sudo aptitude install pulseaudio`
(if you don't have aptitude on your machine: `sudo apt-get install aptitude`)

```
sudo alsa force-reload
pavucontrol
```

The last command should restart the PulseAudio server and launch a desktop application for its settings.

*Note: Using `apt` instead of `apt-get` may work as well.
Reference = https://askubuntu.com/a/435221/1013762
Hope this helps.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work either.  I do have sound, but not a global volume control (the loudspeaker icon).

Answer (score 0):

Hooray -- I got my loudspeaker icon back.  The trick was installing kubuntu-desktop.  Seeing that work explained why none of the other suggested solutions worked. I had been climbing the wrong mountain.